# How to Lexical analysis and tokenization the query in javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing, compiler-construction, tokenize, lexical-analysis

I have a query which is the following where I want to separate the keyword, field value, string or others.

```
query: "tag: AAA, Cust-AAO #sso tag: accounts or tag: cust-acme rana"
```

From the above query need to identify the following separation.

```
tag: = keyword
AAA = field
Cust-AAO = field
#sso = field
tag: = keyword
accounts = field
or = operator
tag: = keyword
cust-acme = field
rana = string
```

Do you have any thought or library which will solve my problem?

Comment: Looks bad if `fields` and `string` can have the same (unpredictable) content. Or is there always a single `string` only at the end of the query?

Comment: @Teemu-callmewhateveryouwant, Bro, Youtrack has already done this for their search. https://jetbrains.github.io/ring-ui/master/index.html?path=/story/components-query-assist--basic

Comment: [here is a list of tokenizers](https://libraries.io/search?keywords=tokenizer&languages=JavaScript). If you describe the language rules in more detail, maybe someone can come up with a solution better tailored to your needs.